# Send image to database using javascript (client side)

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am using an input-tag where the user is able to upload his own image. When it's done, my goal is to send the image to my server (which is a node.js server) and then send it to my database.
How could i do that on the client side ? Should i encode the image file in base64 ?
I just have a function to display the image but i'm not sure if it's useful here.

JS :

```js
avatar.onchange = function() {
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    // get loaded data
    image.src = e.target.result;
  };
  // read the image file as a data URL.
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
};
```

HTML :

```
<input id="avatar" type="file" onchange="previewFile()">
<img id="image" width="200px">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes send it in base64 as it will be easy to store in db and then rebuild whenever needed

Comment: You'll need to deal with that on the server side.

Comment: You should never encode/decode images into database, REALLY BAD practice. You should just create a folder for the files to be uploaded to, then save the URL into the database user's info and on the html side, pull the inage from that url. You can use a library to make it easy on you. https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=uploads+images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have should suffice, as `readAsDataURL` will already encode the file as a base64 string.

In your server, you can save this Data URL directly to your database, but keep in mind that the format for the Data URL string will be as follows:

```
data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data> // data is base64
```

If you need to save or use the file on the server directly, you can strip everything before `<data>` (using Regex or `split`, for example), and save the file with the appropriate extension given the `[<mediatype>]`.

Here's an example of decoding the base64-encoded data in Node with `Buffer`:

```
let buff = Buffer.from(base64string, "base64"); // converts base64 back to binary
```

If you need to decode the base64-encoded data on the browser side, you can use `atob` like so:

```
let data = atob(base64string); // back to decoded string
```